# how to make pdf downloadable using pdf.js (data rendered here unit8array in canvas)

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf.js

I need to make pdf inside scrolalble as canvas width and height is 900x800 and i want to download and print the displayed pdf using client side code.

```
var rob = service.standard.call.payslipPdf.get(payslip).Ev_pdf; //odata service call for pdf base64 data
var pdfText = decode64(rob);
debugger;
var rawLength = pdfText.length;
var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));
for (i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
    array[i] = pdfText.charCodeAt(i);
}

PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
PDFJS.workerSrc = '/module/mycompensation/build/pdf.js';
PDFJS.getDocument(array).then(function (pdf) {
    //code to render pdf on canvas
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The viewer in pdf.js project already has download option. I think in right corner of its toolbar. That should help you with your problem.

Comment: I'm only rendering data to canvas and I need to get it downloadable, print and scroll. Thing you talking abt is completely different and is for displaying pdf in entire window. I have to write or modify viewer.js download, scroll and print functions. Can anyoone help me or guide me with atleast download function just to download context inside canvas and not whole html.